# Remover todos os Espaços em Branco de TextArea

Tags: javascript, jquery

Gostaria de saber como remover todos os espaços em branco de um `textarea`.

Eu tenho um campo `textarea` que copia o valor para um segundo campo `textarea`, gostaria de executar uma função que removesse espaço ou quebra de linha. Minha função não funcionou.

```js
$(function () {

    $('#texto').on('input', function () {
        var texto = $(this).val();
        function trim(texto) {
                return texto.replace(/^\s+|\s+$/g,"");
        }
        $('#convertido1').val(texto);
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<div class="container" style="margin-top:100px">

    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-6">
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="textoOriginal">Insira seu Texto</label>
                <textarea class="form-control" id="texto" class="texto" rows="3"></textarea>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-6">
            <label for="textoConvertido">Insira seu Texto</label>
            <textarea class="form-control" id="convertido1" name="convertido1" rows="3"></textarea>
        </div>
    </div>

</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Tenta assim:

```js
$(function () {
  $('#texto').on('input', function () {
    var texto = $(this).val();
    texto = texto.replace(/^\s+|\s+$/g,"");
    
    $('#convertido1').val(texto);
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<div class="container" style="margin-top:100px">

    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-6">
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="textoOriginal">Insira seu Texto</label>
                <textarea class="form-control" id="texto" class="texto" rows="3"></textarea>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-6">
            <label for="textoConvertido">Insira seu Texto</label>
            <textarea class="form-control" id="convertido1" name="convertido1" rows="3"></textarea>
        </div>
    </div>

</div>
```

OBS.: O regex foi feito pra tirar os espaços e quebras do inicio e do fim do texto somente, se quiser tirar todos os espaços e quebras do texto, basta alterar seu regex para:

```
/\s/g
```

Answer (score 0):

Esse código faz com que dois espaços sejam substituídos por um e a quebra de linha seja removida permitindo que o usuário utilize apenas um espaço para separar o texto.

```js
$(function () {

    $('#texto').on('input', function () {
        let texto = $(this).val().replace(/\s{2,}/g,' ');
        $(this).val($(this).val().replace(/\r?\n|\r/g,'').replace(/\s{2,}/g,' '));
        $('#convertido1').val(texto);
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<div class="container" style="margin-top:100px">

    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-6">
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="textoOriginal">Insira seu Texto</label>
                <textarea class="form-control" id="texto" class="texto" rows="3"></textarea>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-6">
            <label for="textoConvertido">Insira seu Texto</label>
            <textarea class="form-control" id="convertido1" name="convertido1" rows="3"></textarea>
        </div>
    </div>

</div>
```

Mas se quer que não seja permitido nenhum espaço utilize `replace(/\s{2,}/g,'')` no lugar de `replace(/\s{2,}/g,' ')`.